# How to automate video editing and output new videos with scene combinations / permutations?

Tags: automation, video-editing

Is there a way to automate video editing, where it takes an input video and list of timestamps, and then outputs videos with different scene combinations / permutations?

See illustration below, I have a long input video (probably just one, maybe more) with several short scenes. I want to create many videos that have the same intro and outro, but for every video the combinations of the scenes in the middle part is different.

[image]

Ideally I would like to use some sort of scripting language like Python, where I can just create a script that takes the input video and a list of timestamps and then cuts all the new videos together.

It is for a science project and the number of scenes is so large, that it's just not feasable to edit it all by hand in something like Premiere.

Comment: Not sure what editing software you're using there, but Premier Pro and Avid Media Composer can output EDL's (Edit Decision List), which is essentially a text file list of clip names and IN/OUT timecodes. In theory, if you always made sure your clips had the same names and timecodes, you could use the same EDL for all your shoot days and automatically load a sequence based on the pre-defined metadata inside the EDL.

Comment: You can also use AAFs to achieve the same result. Cut a sequence together manually, export as AAF (metadata only), then when you have record a new shoot day just make sure your clip names and timecodes match the previous shoot exactly. Ingest the footage into your editing software in the same way as the previous sequence so clips and timecodes match, then import the AAF you made from the previous sequence and you'll find your new sequence contains all the same cuts with your newly recorded clips.